# Effective method for replicating length function

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, racket

I am replicating racket's length function using just car & cdr to compare then length of two lists and return the shorter of the two.

The length function simply put is:

```
(define length
 (lambda (list)
    (if (null? list)
        0
        (+ 1 (length (cdr list))))))
```

and when used in comparison of two lists

```
(define short
  (lambda (list1 list2)
    (if (<= (length list1) (length list2))
        list1
        list2)))

> (short '(a b c) '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
```

will return '(a b c).

However this method is ineffective especially when one list is much longer than the other, as it will iterate through both lists before returning the shorter.

I have a more effective method below. However I was wondering if there was a more efficient/alternate method to getting the shorter length without checking to the end of both lists. Perhaps by recursively going through the lists simultaneously with car/cdr, until the shorter list reaches its end first.

```
(define shorter?
  (lambda (list1 list2)
    (and (not (null? list2))
         (or (null? list1)
             (shorter? (cdr list1) (cdr list2)))))) 

(define shorter
  (lambda (list1 list2)
    (if (shorter? list2 list1)
        list2
        list1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `shorter?` procedure is *already* as efficient as possible - both the `and` and `or` special forms short-circuit and will stop when the value of any of the evaluated expressions is `true` (for the `or` special form) or `false` (for the `and` special form). So as soon as one of the lists reaches `null`, the recursion stops. Your `shorter?` implementation is equivalent to, and as efficient as this:

```
(define shorter?
  (lambda (list1 list2)
    (cond ((null? list2) #f)
          ((null? list1) #t)
          (else (shorter? (cdr list1) (cdr list2))))))
```

If you want a more compact solution you can put both procedures inside a single procedure, using a named `let` (as demonstrated in the other answer) or an inner helper procedure, both are equivalent. I'll demonstrate the later approach:

```
(define (shorter lst1 lst2)
  (define (shorter-list list1 list2)
    (cond ((null? list2) lst2)
          ((null? list1) lst1)
          (else (shorter-list (cdr list1) (cdr list2)))))
  (shorter-list lst1 lst2))
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'named let' method provides easily understable code. The comments provide the explanation:

```
(define (shorter l1 l2)
  (let loop ((al l2)         ; start with both full lists
             (bl l2))
    (cond
      [(empty? al) l1]       ; if al finishes, return l1 and end; 
      [(empty? bl) l2]       ; if bl finishes, return l2 and end;
      [else
       (loop (cdr al) (cdr bl))] ; else loop again with cdr of lists;
    )))
```

This function will end when shorer list finishes and will not needlessly continue till end of longer list.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend starting like this:

```
(define (shorter list-1 list-2) (shorter-loop list-1 list-2 list-1 list-2))
```

then

```
(define (shorter-loop list-1 list-2 result-1 result-2)
  ;;
  )
```

where the helper function shorter-loop recurses down list-1 and list-2 simultaneously. If list-1 becomes null it returns result-1, if list-2 returns null it returns result-2.

Comment: This does not answer the question